# If violations are fixed, FreezingArchRule automatically reduce the stored violations to prevent a regression.Is there any way to stop this behaviour?

Tags: archunit

I have a Modular Monothic Application in which I have around 10 Modules.
I Have written ArchTest Cases in one of the module which freezes all the existing violations(across all the existing modules) in a file.(Executed in my local by having all the 10 modules in my intellj)

Now When I am executing that test case in Jenkins by checking out only one module.(We are building parallely all the modules in jenkins).It is giving me the below error

```
com.tngtech.archunit.library.freeze.StoreUpdateFailedException: Updating frozen violations is disabled (enable by configuration freeze.store.default.allowStoreUpdate=true)
```

In ArchUnit Tests, If violations are fixed, FreezingArchRule will automatically reduce the known stored violations to prevent any regression.Is there any way to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand correctly that the ArchTest gives fewer violations when building a single module and therefore wants to reduce the violation store, which you don't allow on your Jenkins?

Couldn't you just adapt the `freeze.store.default.allowStoreUpdate` property to allow store updates? That would be the most pragmatic workaround (assuming that Jenkins has write access to these files).

But I would actually recommend using individual violation store files (via an appropriate `freeze.store.default.path` [configuration](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_configuration), e.g. pointing to a relative path in each module) to avoid any coupling between modules which may or may not be checked out.

To answer your question whether it is possible to stop `FreezingArchRule` to automatically reduce the known stored violations: Technically, you could use a custom Violation Store that just does not save violations such as

```java
class NonSavingTextFileBasedViolationStore implements ViolationStore {

    private final ViolationStore delegate = new TextFileBasedViolationStore();

    @Override
    public void initialize(Properties properties) {
        delegate.initialize(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(ArchRule rule) {
        return delegate.contains(rule);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(ArchRule rule, List<String> violations) {
        // do not save
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getViolations(ArchRule rule) {
        return delegate.getViolations(rule);
    }
}
```

See the [Violation Store documentation](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_violation_store) how to configure `FreezingArchRule` to use it.